# Redirect contact form 7 with javascript

Tags: javascript, contact-form-7

I do not want to use the additional setting because its filled with a bunch of analytics code. I want to my javascript function to fire when the button is clicked. example the contact form 7's button ID is #aircraft_submit.
I have tried the following

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
        jQuery('').click(function(){
            document.getElementById("#aircraft_submit").onclick = function(){
                window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

I think I might be understanding contact form 7 incorrectly. Please note I do not want to use additional option in contact form 7 at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seen as you are using jquery anyway, you can add the click on the submit button like this

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#aircraft_submit").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location.href  = "http://stackoverflow.com";
    });
}
```

You'll need to prevent the default 'submit' action

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, This function does not seem to work either. It seems like nothing gets fired when that button is clicked

Comment: where/how are you including your code? if you put `debugger;` after the doc ready, does it fire in dev tools?

Comment: Is does not fire in there either. So I am assuming it never even gets to my javascript :/

Comment: Yes sounds like it. how are you including the script?